# How to apply interceptor in Angular only to POST requests?

Tags: angular, interceptor, angular-httpclient-interceptors

Is it possible to apply interceptors in Angular only to POST requests?

Answer (score 2):

Within the `intercept` method of your interceptor, will have a `req` parameter, which is of type `HttpRequest`. This class has a property, `method` which will be `post` if the HTTP method of the request was `POST`.